# Mongo express not loading porperly

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, mongo-express

I have been trying to learn "Docker Tutorial for Beginners [FULL COURSE in 3 Hours] by Tech world with Nana". I installed and configured everything as per the video, unfortunately I didn't get the actual output. which is, when I call the IP with port it need to show mongo db web page, but my ouput was "page load error".

Containers are running
[image]

#docker logs mongo-express

### Welcome to mongo-express

(node:7) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
Mongo Express server listening at http://0.0.0.0:8081
Server is open to allow connections from anyone (0.0.0.0)
basicAuth credentials are "admin:pass", it is recommended you change this in your config.js!

================================

#docker logs dbbb5a4bf9b4

about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 29

{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-12T14:20:19.242+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"-","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-12T14:20:19.244+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-12T14:20:19.244+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"main","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":

[image]

Commands I used are

```
docker run -d -p8081:8081 -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password --net mongo-network --name mongo-express -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb mongo-express

docker run -p27017:27017 -d -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password --name mongodb --net mongo-network mongo
```

Full log is submitted in pastebin.
pastebin.com/zaRvEepp

Comment: try: this `Clinent.connect(ConnectionStrinng, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})` ??

Comment: Bro, i have no idea about this, 
######to create mongo express : docker run -d -p8081:8081 -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password --net mongo-network --name mongo-express -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb mongo-express
#################

#### To create mongodb
docker run -p27017:27017 -d -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password --name mongodb --net mongo-network mongo

These are the commands I used to create the container